# How do I change position of a help popup window in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have the code below which now shows a standard windows help popup where available.  Does anyone know if there is a way of positioning where this window appears?  For example, to make it appear where the user has clicked?

```
function HelpPopupWindow(Command: Word; Data: Integer; var CallHelp: Boolean): Boolean;
var
  dwIDs: array[0..3] of DWord;
begin
  dwIDs[0] := Handle;
  dwIDs[1] := Data;
  dwIDs[2] := 0;
  dwIDs[3] := 0;

  HtmlHelp(Handle, PChar('HELP FILE LOCATION HERE::/cshelp.txt'), HH_TP_HELP_CONTEXTMENU, DWORD(@dwIDs[0]));

  CallHelp := False;
end;
```

Cheers

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`HH_DISPLAY_TEXT_POPUP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/ms670082) to display the popup help. This gives you more flexibility through the [`HH_POPUP`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/ms524362) structure that you pass. Use the `pt` field to specify the position:

> Specifies (in pixels) where the top center of the pop-up window should be located.

The [Helpware](http://helpware.net/htmlhelp/how_to_whatsthis.htm#chmtext) site gives some sample Delphi code:

```
{Show HH Popup using a string (StringID) from text file in a CHM
StringID: eg. 99; CHMTextFile: eg. _runDir + 'help.chm::/cshelp.txt'}
function HH_ShowPopupHelp3(aParent: TForm; StringID: Integer; 
  CHMTextFile: String; XYPos: TPoint): HWND;
var hhpopup: HH.THHPopup;
begin
  with hhpopup do
  begin
    cbStruct := sizeof(hhpopup); //sizeof this structure
    hinst := 0; //no used 
    idString := StringID; //topic number in a text file.
    pszText := nil; //no used
    pt := XYPos; //top center of popup
    clrForeground := COLORREF(-1); //use -1 for default - RGB value
    clrBackground := COLORREF(-1); //use -1 for default - RGB value
    rcMargins := Rect(-1,-1,-1,-1);//amount of space between edges
    pszFont := ''; 
  end;
  Result := HtmlHelp(aParent.Handle, PChar(CHMTextFile), 
  HH_DISPLAY_TEXT_POPUP, DWORD(@hhpopup));
end;
```

In fact I think you already found this page judging by your code, but just needed to read a bit further down the page.

Comment: Hi David, I did see this code but I dont know where THHPopup is defined?

Comment: Get it from Windows.pas. It's called `THH_Popup`.